# Is there any way to hide the arrow on a ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to hide the arrow on a `ToolStripMenuItem`? The arrow is enclosed in the red square.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Remove the sub-menu items?

Comment: You will probably have to override the `OnPaint` method and draw it to your liking.

Comment: @LarsTech it looks like that the OP wants to keep the subItems, that's a little strange unless he wants another style of arrow.

Comment: @KingKing that's right - I'm actually embedding a control with a picture box to have a preview of what the parent item looks like. Sorry this image isn't clear.

Comment: @LarsTech +1 :) my first thought exacly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found this is very helpful, you can create your own custom ToolStripRenderer inherits from `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`, like this:

```
public class CustomToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{       
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {            
        e.ArrowRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;//Don't draw arrow
        base.OnRenderArrow(e);
    }
}
//and update the Renderer property of your MenuStrip
menuStrip1.Renderer = new CustomToolStripRenderer();
```

### UPDATE

For your requirement, there are some ways to do but I think this is a good way:

```
public class CustomToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{       
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {                                    
        if (RenderArrow != null) RenderArrow(this, e);
        base.OnRenderArrow(e);            
    }
    public new event ToolStripArrowRenderEventHandler RenderArrow;//This will hide the default RenderArrow event which can't help you change the e argument because the default is fired after the Arrow is rendered.
}
//Now you have to create your own List<ToolStripItem> to contain all the items whose arrows should not be rendered
List<ToolStripItem> ItemsWithoutArrow = new List<ToolStripItem>();
//Add a method to add an item to that list
private void SuppressDrawArrow(ToolStripItem item)
{
   if (!ItemsWithoutArrow.Contains(item)) ItemsWithoutArrow.Add(item);
}
//Assign custom ToolStripRenderer for your MenuStrip
menuStrip1.Renderer = new CustomToolStripRenderer();
//Now add a RenderArrow event handler, this RenderArrow event is the new we created in the class CustomToolStripRenderer
((CustomToolStripRenderer)menuStrip1.Renderer).RenderArrow += (s, e) =>
 {                
    if(ItemsWithoutArrow.Contains(e.Item)) e.ArrowRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
 };
//Add some item to the ItemsWithoutArrow to test
SuppressDrawArrow(item1ToolStripMenuItem);
```

Another solution (I like many solutions to a problem :)

```
public class CustomToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{       
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {                                    
       if(!itemsWithoutArrow.Contains(e.Item)) base.OnRenderArrow(e);            
    }
    public void SuppressDrawArrow(ToolStripItem item){
       if (!itemsWithoutArrow.Contains(item)) itemsWithoutArrow.Add(item);
    }
    public void AllowDrawArrow(ToolStripItem item){
       itemsWithoutArrow.Remove(item);
    }
    private List<ToolStripItem> itemsWithoutArrow = new List<ToolStripItem>();
}
//Use in code
CustomToolStripRenderer renderer = new CustomToolStripRenderer();
renderer.SuppressDrawArrow(item1ToolStripMenuItem);
menuStrip1.Renderer = renderer;    
//This solution fits your requirement (draw or don't draw arrow) but if you also want to change such as ArrowColor, the previous solution would be better.
```

I've found that we can render it freely with many options. That's great :)

Comment: That's pretty cool and it works universally. Is it possible to have it work for only one `ToolStripMenuItem`? So it would be a specific drop down on the MenuStrip.

Comment: @IanO'Brien: In `OnRenderArrow`, check whether `e.Item` is the `ToolStripMenuItem` you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this - I really appreciate it. I hope this helps someone else since I couldn't find any question like this on SO.